# Servlet Filters are not working properly

Tags: java, mysql, servlet-filters

I have created a java web-app MySQL as DB in Netbeans 7.4. I have used filters to control the unauthorized access but it is not working properly.**I have my index.jsp (as login page), home.jsp and Add_Details.jsp files. I want that when session is null or if the user try to access anothers page (except index.jsp) then they redirect to index.jsp. but it is not working.**  Here is my code:-

**AuthenticationFilter.java**

```
package Filters;
 //all mandatory files are imported.

public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
        this.context.log("AuthenticationFilter initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        String uri = req.getRequestURI();
        this.context.log("Requested Resource::" + uri);

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        if (session == null && !(uri.endsWith("index.jsp") || !uri.endsWith("Bucket/") || !uri.endsWith("LoginServlet"))) 
        {
            this.context.log("Unauthorized access request");
            res.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
        } else {
            // pass the request along the filter chain
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // close any resources here
    }
}
```

**LogingRequestFilter.java**

```
public class LoggingRequestFilter implements Filter {

    private ServletContext context;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        this.context = fConfig.getServletContext();
        this.context.log("RequestLoggingFilter initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        Enumeration<String> params = req.getParameterNames();
        while (params.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = params.nextElement();
            String value = request.getParameter(name);
            this.context.log(req.getRemoteAddr() + "::Request Params::{" + name
                    + "=" + value + "}");
        }

        Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                this.context.log(req.getRemoteAddr() + "::Cookie::{"
                        + cookie.getName() + "," + cookie.getValue() + "}");
            }
        }
        // pass the request along the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // we can close resources here
    }
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoggingRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.org.king.Filters.LoggingRequestFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.org.king.Filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoggingRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
  <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend setting up a breakpoint within your Servlet Filter and walk through the code to understand why the flow of execution is not getting inside your "if" block:

```
if (session == null && !(uri.endsWith("index.jsp") || !uri.endsWith("Bucket/") || !uri.endsWith("LoginServlet"))) 
{
```

Also, if you are implementing this from scratch, you might want to keep minds principles like "DTSTTCPW" and "YAGNI".
*DTSTTCPW = Do the simplest thing that could possibly work
**YAGNI = You Aren't Going to Need it

Czech this out:
[Java Filter to redirect users who are not logged in to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225221/java-filter-to-redirect-users-who-are-not-logged-in-to-login-page)

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago i had a similar problem.

It's not enough to check is session is null in that way. you probably have an object that you bind to that session. I had user for example. in the login page i bind user object to the session.

check whether that object is null or not. do not use session.

because browser might have created the session or session might be new, but you didn't put any  login info to it yet.