# Redirect to external URL servlet filter

Tags: servlets, wicket

I'm having trouble redirecting the user in servlet filter.

```
@WebFilter(value = "/*", initParams = { @WebInitParam(name = "applicationClassName", value = "com.sample.Application"),
@WebInitParam(name="filterMappingUrlPattern", value="/*") })
public class CertFilter extends WicketFilter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        if(USER_MATCHES_CONDITION){
            httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "https://google.com");
            httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("https://google.com");
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
    }
}
```

The request to google.com is done but user is not redirected to there. The request intercepted meaning USER_MATCHES_CONDITION is met at the time when stylesheet is requested. Thus redirection request header is `Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1`. So I get a warning Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html. Probably this is the reason why it's not redirecting.

How to intercept random request and redirect it to external url?

**EDIT:** Even if I do just like this:

```
@Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("https://google.com");
        return;
    }
```

It does not redirect the user... I'm guessing wicket overrides it somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10225221/java-filter-to-redirect-users-who-are-not-logged-in-to-login-page

Comment: It may be similar but adding `return;` does not help the cause.

Comment: Please create a demo application and share it with us. For example put it at GitHub.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want this behavior to be molded into the `WicketFilter`, as opposed to a separate `Filter` implementation which then sits on top of `WicketFilter`?

Comment: Regular filter does not have `AuthWebSession` available. But I gave up on redirecting in filter and used client polling.